# Where can I find papers and research on the Alternating Hurwitz Zeta Function?

Tags: reference-request, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions, beta-function

The function is as follows (I don't know it's name, it could be 'Generalised Dirichlet Eta Function') $$f(s,q)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{(n+q)^{s}}$$

Comment: Check references about the Lerch Zeta function which contains this for $\lambda=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: There is a lot of material on the Lerch Transcendent with lots of values of all three variables, so what you said is harder than it sounds.

Comment: $\sum_{n \ge 0} (-1)^n (n+q)^{-s}=2^{-s} \zeta(s,q/2) - 2^{-s}\zeta(s,(q+1)/2))$ gives the functional equation, analytic continuation, density of zeros, particular values, growth estimates. Then it depends on why you want to look at those.

Comment: @JoshuaFarrell:  FWIW, Googling "alternating Hurwitz zeta function"+"latest research" returns only four papers on the topic, which you might want to look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Where can I find papers and research on the Alternating Hurwitz Zeta Function?*

Probably, a good starting point is at [MathSciNet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathSciNet) and [ScienceDirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ScienceDirect), which give, for example:

---

- [Identities for the Hurwitz zeta function, Gamma function, and L-functions](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11139-013-9468-0)
  [image]

---

- [Another discrete Fourier transform pairs associated with the Lipschitz–Lerch zeta function](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0096300311015153)
  [image]

---

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, your function is related to the [Lerch transcendent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerch_zeta_function) $\Phi (z,s,q)$. Here
$$\Phi(z,s,q) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{(n + q)^s}.$$ 
Setting $z = -1$ gives
$$\Phi (-1,s,q) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(n + q)^s},$$
which is your $f (s,q)$.

Much is known about the Lerch transcendent. For example, when $q = 1$ we have
$$\Phi(-1,s,1) = \eta (s),$$
where $\eta (s)$ is the Dirichlet eta function.

Comment: The problem is that the Lerch transcendent doesn't have several of the interesting properties of $\zeta(s,q)$ and $\sum_n (-1)^n (n+q)^{-s} = 2^{-s} \zeta(s,q/2)-2^{-s} \zeta(s,(q+1)/2)$